# Find FFT and summation in 4D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, fft

Please, I have `F(8*409600*3)`  matrix. I want to reshape it into `B(8*512*3*800)` matrix (each row should divide into `800` parts) then I have to find Fast Fourier transform`(FFT)` for each `(8*512)` rows and multiply it by its conjugate and divide by a constant  after that I have to find summation of elements of each row in fourth dimension and average them by the number of slices within the fourth dimension `(800)`. I mean

```
(B(1,1,1,1) +B(1,1,1,2)+B(1,1,1,3)……+B(1,1,1,800))/800
(B(1,2,1,1) +B(1,2,1,2)+B(1,2,1,3)……+B(1,2,1,800))/800
```

And so on for each row.

I used below code it seems work but does not give a correct result.

```
 F=rand(8,409600,3);
 B=reshape(F,8,512,3,[]);
 C1=fft(B, [],2);
 C2=C1.*conj(C1);
 C3=C2/(3000);
 C4=sum(C3,4)/800;
```

Thanks

Comment: (1) How do you know it’s not the right result, when your input data is random? Is `C4` the wrong size? (2) `B` is four-dimensional. Do you want to take the 1D FFT on the third dimension, or the 2D FFT on the third & fourth dimensions? (Your code is taking a 1D FFT along the *second* dimension, which is 512-elements long.) (3) `F`’s second dimension has length 409600 = 512*800. But that `reshape` will *not* keep those 409600 elements together: `B`’s third dimension (length three) is between 512 and 800. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Regarding (3) above: consider a simplified 2D example: `F = [1:10; 101:110; 1001:1010]'`. `F` is 10 by 3, and contains one through ten starting at 0, 100, and 1000. If I do `B1 = reshape(F, 5, 2, []))`, the first dimension of length ten will get split into two dimensions, of lengths five and two, and more importantly, they’ll be kept together: `B1(:, :, 1)`, the first ‘page’ of `B` will be `1:5` and `6:10` as two columns. *However*, `B2 = reshape(F, 5, [], 2)` will do something very different and `B2` will have `F`’s three columns mixed together. I’m not sure you want that.

Comment: @Ahmed Fasih, Thank you. I have the plot for the result that's how I know it's not correct.I have the real data but this is just an example.My original data is 8*409600*3 and I need to find the average of PSD (power spectral density) and in order to do that, I have to break (8*409600) into 800 parts each part has 512 points. After that, I have to find FFT for each 512 points then multiply by conjugate and divide by constant which is here (number of points*frequency resolution)after that I will get the PSD for one row which has 512 points.

Comment: I have 800 row I need to do that for all then I have to find the average of PSD by sum all column and dividing by 800. I want to take FFT for each row in the second dimension. I want to keep each slice together after reshape. B1(:, :, 1) that's why I used B=reshape(F,8,512,3,[]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to try `B = reshape(F, 8, 512, [], 3);` to get 8 by 512 by 800 by 3 array.

Then do `C1 = abs(fft(B, [], 2)).^2;` to take the 512-point FFT and convert the spectrum to a power spectrum. (Note that for complex `c`, `conj(c) * c == abs(c)^2` to machine precision.)

Then you want to average those 800 512-point PSDs: `C2 = squeeze(mean(C1, 3));`. If you don’t use `squeeze` here, you’ll have 8 by 512 by 1 by 3 array, and `squeeze` just eliminates the 1-length dimensions, leaving `C2` to be a 8 by 512 by 3 array.  I prefer to use `mean` here instead of sum and divide because it’s more obvious what you’re trying to achieve.

Finally, you seem to have a `3000` factor, so: `C3 = C2 / 3000;`.

---

Here’s how I’m thinking about your problem. You have eight sensors (microphone, photodiode, whatever). Each sensor collects 409600 samples. You do this for three days. So you have your original `F` matrix that’s 8 by 409600 by 3.

Now, you want to see how the power spectral density changes for each sensor over the three days. So you split up each sensor/day’s 409600 samples into 800 chunks, and each chunk gets 512 samples—no overlap between chunks. In the code above, you take each 512-long chunk’s FFT and average all 800 of them. This leaves you with a 8 by 512 by 3 array, and you now have what you wanted: an estimate of each sensor’s PSD for each day.

Comment: Thank you so much. exactly I have data from a microphone (I have eight microphones)  and each microphone has (1*409600) and I did that for three cases. so I got (8*409600*3). I have to find PSD (the average PSD for each microphone and in order to do that I used above procedure)